# Implicit conversion from enumeration type 'enum UIDeviceOrientation' to different enum type 'UIInterfaceOrientation' 'enum UIInterfaceOrientation

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, notifications, uiinterfaceorientation

I am using Xcode 5.0.2 and getting the following warning when trying to compile my objective C code:

> Implicit conversion from enumeration type 'enum UIDeviceOrientation'
>   to different enumeration type 'UIInterfaceOrientation' (aka 'enum
>   UIInterfaceOrientation')

The warning is in viewController.m

```
-(void)youTubeStarted:(NSNotification *)notification{
    // your code here
    NSLog(@"youTubeStarted");
    **[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarOrientation:UIDeviceOrientationPortrait animated:NO];**
}

-(void)youTubeFinished:(NSNotification *)notification{
    // your code here
    NSLog(@"youTubeFinished");
}

- (void)youTubeVideoExit:(id)sender {
    **[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarOrientation:UIDeviceOrientationPortrait animated:NO];**
}
```

Comment: Use "UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait" instead of "UIDeviceOrientationPortrait"

Comment: `- (void)setStatusBarOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation animated:(BOOL)animated`

Comment: @EDUsta Please post your comment as an answer so that I can accept the answer.

Comment: hoiberg42 has the same answer, you may accept that as well. Happy codings :)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It means that you have used the wrong enum type: You have used `UIDeviceOrientation` instead of `UIInterfaceOrientation`.
To fix this, simply replace `UIDeviceOrientationPortrait` with `UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait`.